# Is 'liege' masculine?

Tags: grammatical-gender

'Liege' seems to most often refer to a man.  Is that because most lords in history and fiction are men, or because 'liege' is a masculine noun?  If the latter, is there a feminine counterpart?

Comment: English nouns do not generally have grammatical gender. Vestiges of it survive in a few loan words, but it has no grammatical function in English.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not meaning to ask about strict grammatical gender.  What are the proper terms for gendered terms like 'milkman' and 'congresswomen' if not 'masculine' and 'feminine'?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no feminine form of the noun *liege.*  There are obvious historical reasons for this, but I lack the knowledge to give an apt explanation.

However, the decidedly masculine phrase *liege lord* was also quite common and more or less identical in meaning.  Although I have never knowingly come across it in reading, the obvious feminine form of this is *liege lady.*  [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=liege%20lady,%20liege%20lord&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,liege%20lady;,c0;.t1;,liege%20lord;,c0) leads me to believe that *liege lady* is used at least occasionally.

The more direct feminine form would seem to be *liegess,* but I have never seen or heard it used, nor does Google Ngram display a single instance of it.

Answer (score 1):

> **Liege** (adj.)
> word used by a vassal to address his superior or lord in the feudal system, c.1300, from Anglo-French lige (late 13c.), Old French lige "(feudal) liege, free, giving or receiving fidelity," perhaps from Late Latin laeticus "cultivated by serfs," from laetus "serf," which probably is from Proto-Germanic *lethiga- "freed" (cognates: Old English læt "half-freedman, serf;" Old High German laz, Old Frisian lethar "freedman"), from PIE root *le- "let go, slacken" (see let (v.)). Or the Middle English word may be directly from Old High German leidig "free." As a noun from late 14c., both as "vassal" and "lord." **Hence, liege-man** "a vassal sworn to the service and support of a lord, who in turn is obliged to protect him" (mid-14c.).
>
> Source: Etymonline

It's origin, anyway, seems to support your view on its use being mainly referred to men.

Answer (score 1):

> “In general, my liege lady,’ he began, ‘Women desire to have dominion Over their husbands, and their lovers too; They want to have mastery over them. That’s what you most desire—even if my life Is forfeit. I am here; do what you like.”
>
> ― Geoffrey Chaucer, The Canterbury Tales

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).